# Customize TFS Build to include only specific files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, incremental-build

I have a solution file with multiple projects that I am trying to configure for continuous integration on a development server using Team Foundation Server. I would like to customize this to only deploy the changes that were checked in.

**Scenario example**

- Projects

  - My Project (MVC app)
  - Logic Layer

A user checks in a new **Home.cshtml file** and updates a code file in the **Logic Layer**. I would like to configure the automated build to just build the following package:

- My Project

  - bin/MyLogic.dll
  - Views/Home.cshtml

What steps are done to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having? Is it deploying the entire web application?

Comment: The problem: I get a build with all files needed to run the application. It looks like the same process that occurs when you do a publish for VS.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean "I get a build"? Does it _build_ every project? That is, do all of the DLLs get new dates every time you check in, say, a .cshtml file?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. The entire solution is built and all files and dll's get updated to a new date. Any file properties marked with Include (Content, Compile) get packaged up in the build. The entire application is packaged in a revision folder with the dll's at the root and a sub folder with all the files needed for the app. So if I check in a .cshtml file I will then have all files needed to run the application including /css /scrips /views / bin/*.* /web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an incremental build, though I don't recall if it was supported back in TFS 2010.

Try configuring the build to not clean the workspace. Set the "Clean Workspace" property in the "Basic" section to "None".

Then, it will keep the binaries from the previous build, and, just like Visual Studio, will only build targets for which the inputs have changed.

Comment: I do have Clean Workspace set to None. Could this be because I am adding the files to a drop folder instead of the directory that has the application?

Comment: How are you "adding the files to a drop folder"?

Comment: Build definition set up in Team Explorer to do continuous integration (Build each check in). It is set to take from a specific branch in source control and the staging location is set to a UNC share on the development server. So when a check in occurs the build controller does the work of adding it to the UNC share if build and unit tests are successful.

Comment: No, that doesn't affect what gets built. The only things that should affect that are timestamps of input and output files.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will do some more research on incremental builds and see if I can apply this to the environment.

Comment: If you need more control and details, you may take a look at my series of blog posts, starting http://blog.casavian.eu/blog/2014/04/23/increment-version-for-changed-assemblies-only-first-part/